# Facebook Graph Public Checkins & Locations

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In facebook graph api there's an option of pulling " public " information - i.e - searching for posts of users who are not friends of you and thier users are not considered " private " .

I wondered whether there's an option to pull "public information" such as users (who are not my friends) checkins. I haven't found such option in facebook graph api , but if there's an option of pulling public posts data , it makes sense that pulling checkins data is also available.

I'd like to know if such option exist , 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to use profile ID to lookup public information of that user?

Comment: I want to pull checkins data of users which thier facebook data is not private. There's an option to pull public posts, I'm now searching for a query that also pulls 'public' checkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using type=checkin in a the same [query](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=hate%20my%20boss&type=checkin) itmar posted in the comment results in OAuthException 104 "An access token is required to request this resource." So it seems that public posts are available for search, but public checkins are not.

Would've added this as a comment but I don't have the rep yet.